# How can repair this error? "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm trying to do a game with `andengine library`.

When the Sprite `Enemy1Sprite` reach the top of the camera, and I detach it, this exception is thrown :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Invalid Index 12 size is 12
```

I have to detach the `enemy1Sprite` because it keep creating Sprites of bullets out of the camera.

This is the code.

***Class enemy1 :***

```
    package es.uah.juegomentos;

    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
    import org.anddev.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
    import org.anddev.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
    import org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegion;

    public class Enemy1 extends Sprite {

boolean abajo = true;

public Enemy1(TextureRegion pTextureRegion) {
    super(0, 0, pTextureRegion);

    this.setPosition(JuegoMentosActivity.RANDOM.nextInt(JuegoMentosActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH), -10);
    TimerHandler Enemy1fire = new TimerHandler(0.75f, true, enemigo1fireCallback);  
    JuegoMentosActivity.getmGameScene().registerUpdateHandler(Enemy1fire);
}

@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

    float y = getY();

    if (y >= 275) {abajo = false;}

    if (abajo)  {y = y + pSecondsElapsed * 125.0f;}
    else {y = y - pSecondsElapsed * 125.0f;}



    this.setPosition(getX(), y);
    if (getY()<-10){this.getParent().detachChild(this);}
}

ITimerCallback enemigo1fireCallback = new ITimerCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

        bala1 mbala1;

        mbala1 = new bala1(getX()+(64*1/2),getY()+64,JuegoMentosActivity.getMbala1Texture().getTextureRegion(),true);
        JuegoMentosActivity.getmGameScene().attachChild(mbala1);
    }
};
    }
```

***Create new enemy in the scene :***

```
    //Creamos el sprite del enemigo uno
    ITimerCallback enemigo1CreatorCallback = new ITimerCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

            mEnemy1Sprite = new Enemy1(mEnemy1Texture.getTextureRegion());
            mGameScene.attachChild(mEnemy1Sprite);  
        }               
    };

     TimerHandler Enemy1Creator = new TimerHandler(3.0f, true, enemigo1CreatorCallback);
    mGameScene.registerUpdateHandler(Enemy1Creator);
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered posting the part of the code that actually *throws* the exception? And while you are at it, the *complete* exception stack?

Comment: By the way, a quick google search would show you that the last index of an array of size 12 is actually 11, since array indexes are 0-based in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question really - Marcelo is correct, the issue is not in the code you posted, it's where you are doing the detachChild call - you need to call that on the Update Thread, as in

```
runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    yourScene.detachChild(yourEnemySprite);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This says that your actual array size is 12 so your last index is 11. But you are trying to access index 12 which does not exist. Try to find out the line which throws this error. Make a condition there that `if size of index is >= size of array brake`.

Also you may try using `try{}catch(IndexOutOfBondException e){}` and continue the process.

Comment: This answer sounds likely to be correct. But also - there is a function you might like: detachSelf(); instead of this.getParent().detachChild(this);

Answer (score 0):

detach entity in onManagedUpdate of scene.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. This looks like a comment, not an answer.